# durch oder über den Marktplatz, die Fußgängerzone

Tags: preposition

I would use **durch** for both *die Fußgängerzone* and *der Marktplatz,* but in a text in my textbook,

> **über** den Marktplatz

was used. Which one is correct then?

Comment: How would you say it in English? "Through the market square" sounds like ploughing through the cobble stones. "Over the market square" sounds right.

Answer (score 5):

A *Platz* (town square) is the **surface** of a larger area on the ground. You can not be **in** a town square. This would mean, that half of you body is stuck in the ground. You can be **auf** (on) a *Platz.* You just can walk through the air above the square, but not through the square itself.

A *Zone* (zone) is a region with some specific rules/laws. So you can be **in** a zone and you can walk **through** it.

Comment: You can actually be in a place (Ort). But you can't be in a (market) square [(Markt)platz]. Place = Ort, Platz = square.

Comment: FWIW: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Town_square. Not "town place".

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Was ist mit z.B. mit dem Eaton Place in London?

Comment: Das ist ein Platz der "Ort" im Namen hat. Oder auch nicht: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eaton_Square. Wie es aussieht, ist Eaton Place die Ortschaft um den Platz. Sowie Peyton Place.

Answer (score 5):

**Durch** means you are inside the item and pass through it while **über** means you cross it.

> Ich bin durch das Gewimmel über den Marktplatz gegangen.

*I crossed the market square through the masses.*

It gets interesting as soon both options are valid:

> Das Schiff fuhr durch den Ärmelkanal.

*The ship passed the English Channel.* (It's a ship going east-west.)

> Das Schiff fuhr über den Ärmelkanal.

*The ship crossed the English Channel.* (It's a ferry, Dover-Calais.)

Answer (score 1):

Your textbook is correct, but I disagree with the essentials of the previous answers. I doubt that it is possible to define the correct usage with logic or rules. You simply have to learn which preposition to use and what it means.

Hubert Schölnast e.g. writes:

> A Platz (town square) is the surface of a larger area on the ground.
>   You can not be in a town square. This would mean, that half of you
>   body is stuck in the ground.

A *Park* (park) can also be described as the surface of a larger area on the ground. With some greens or plants on a *Platz* (square), the distinction between *Park* and *Platz* can even be quite fluent. Nevertheless you are *in einem Park* not *auf einem Park* and you can walk *durch den Park* and not *über den Park*, although you are *auf einem Platz* and walk *über den Platz*. Being *in einem Park* certainly does not mean that your body is stuck in the ground. There are also other compositions with *Platz*, which allow the usage of *durch*. e.g. *durch den Campingplatz gehen* (camping site).

It is neither obvious to me that a *Platz* refers to the surface of the square. I would rather, just as with a *Fußgängerzone* define it as a certain area.

Then there are locations where you can use both *durch* and *über*. If we stay with very related concepts, you can walk both *durch einen Markt* and *über einen Markt* (marked). In this case, both prepositions can to a certain extent be used interchangeably, although my stomach says that *durch den Markt gehen* is rather the act of passing through a market with the purpose of reaching something at the other side, while *über den Markt gehen* is more about strolling around at the market to watch or shop. I would even say that if *Markt* is used in the meaning of an indoor shop, you can only walk *durch den Markt* and not *über den Markt*.

Comment: The question was specifically about *der Marktplatz*, which is different from *der Markt*. Sure, one can go *durch den Markt* because it's an arrangement of boothes and shoppers to pass through.

Comment: @Janka I am not sure what you are trying to say, but if you are attempting to justify your explanation that '*durch* means you are inside the item', how does that match with Park and Campingplatz and why can you be 'inside' a pedestrian zone, but not inside the area called a market square?

Comment: Because *durch den Platz* means crossing through the flat surface. That makes no sense. You cannot be *im Platz* either, it has to be *auf dem Platz*. Puzzling, for *der Hof*, it depends on dialect.

Comment: @Janka Noone with a sane mind would interpret *durch den Marktplatz* as crossing through the surface of the ground. Coming to think of an example, I would e.g. much rather say *der Bach verläuft durch den Marktplatz* than using *über* in this context and that does not mean that the water is disappearing through a hole in the ground. Your attempt to use logic here is puzzling and does not make sense to me.

Comment: Can't help it then.

Comment: @Janka It would be helpful if you answered my questions instead of just resigning. I can try again: Why can one (according to your explanation) be 'inside' a pedestrian zone, 'inside' a yard *(Hof)*, 'inside' a camping site and 'inside' a park, but not 'inside' a town square? And since you explain the usage of *in/an* or *durch/über* with this 'inside' definition, you can't explain the 'inside' definition with a recursive reference back to the usage of in/an.

Comment: How should I do that? I know my explanation *works*, even with the *der Hof* example. It all depends if the item is considered something to be on/crossed or something considered to be in/passed.

Comment: @jarnbjo Dein Beispiel mit dem Bach ist doch eine Bestätigung von Jankas Aussage. Ein Bach schneidet sich in den Untergrund hinein, deswegen fließt der Bach normalerweise durch den Marktplatz, wenn überhaupt. Trat er jedoch wg. eines außergewöhnlichen Hochwassers über die Ufer und fließt nur über die Oberfläche, sagte man in der Tat, er fließe über den Marktplatz. Da zu einem Park auch Büsche, Sträucher, Hecken und Bäume gehören ist man nicht einfach über der Oberfläche sondern zwischen den Pflanzen.

Comment: @userunknown Nein. Wenn ein Bach durch einen Marktplatz verläuft, dann tritt der Bach in der Ebene auf einer Seite des Platzes ein, verläuft in der gleichen Richtung wie eine Person, die sich *über* den Platz bewegt und tritt auf der anderen Seite wieder aus. Der Bach kommt nicht von oben und verläuft nach unten durch ein Loch in der Oberfläche.

Comment: Ein Bach verläuft also durch einen Marktplatz, er verläuft nicht über den Marktplatz? Ich habe keine weiteren Fragen.