# "mitten in" or "mitten auf"?

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case

To say "in the middle of (something)" - when should one use "mitten IN" and when should one use "mitten AUF" ?

Also, is this always used with `dative` or is it different sometimes ?

For instance:

1) Er rennt mitten in/auf der Nacht.

2) Er rennt mitten in/auf der Strasse.

3) Die Kugel traf ihn mitten in/auf die/der Stirn.

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. What did your dictionary tell you as differences between `in` and `auf`? In case english is (close enough to be) your mother tongue - how would you write these examples in english to express your desired intention? (I assume some expamples might then feel self explanatory) PS: please use not only "in the middle of" for your examples.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm why do you need the examples in English? Just curious, what can you deduce from their translations.

Comment: On would use "mittin in" for places where one would use "in", and "mitten auf" for places where one would use "auf" - it's as simple as that. Both "in" and "auf" can be used with accusative and dative, and the same applies for "mitten in" and "mitten auf" too.

Comment: @RHa Why the answer in the comments?

Comment: @c.p. to get more from the intention of an example from OP. translating everything with "in the middle of" limits me in understanding/ hinting the difference. Because I see differences and as there was earlier the question about "über vs. durch", it came to my mind that a similiar difference is taken place here.

Comment: Thanks all of you for your comments ! With them and the answers below, I think I get it now. Cheers !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) Er rennt mitten in der Nacht.

*time*

More examples:

- mitten am Tag
- mitten in der Stunde

> 2) Er rennt auf der Straße. or Er rennt mitten auf der Straße.

*place*

More examples:

- Er rennt mitten auf dem Weg.
- Er rennt mitten auf der Tartanbahn.
- Er rennt mitten auf dem Marktplatz. / Er rennt über den Marktplatz.

> 3a) Die Kugel traf ihn mitten in die Stirn.

*It is the place and in additional it is emphasized that it got under the skin or into the head.*

> 3b) Die Kugel traf ihn mitten auf der Stirn.

*Its the place on your forehead.*

[edit]

> 2b) Er rennt in der Straße.

*Yes, it is possible, but it emphasizes the street with its name. E. g.*

> Er rennt (mitten) in der Bahnhofsstraße.

Then you say more:

> Er rennt durch die Bahnhofsstraße.

*It depends on the context.*

Comment: I can also "in der Straße rennen". See similiar case: https://german.stackexchange.com/a/48119/36160

Comment: And of course, "mitten auf die Straße" is possible, as well.

Comment: Thanks Jean for your detailed answer ! And thanks also to Shegit Brahm and O.R. Mapper for their helpful comments !

Comment: Beware that "place" does nto imply "auf":  mitten im Raum, mitten im Gewühl, mitten im Rampenlicht. Also, while *in die Stirn* emphasizes direction, I would still say *in die Stirn* for the place (But "Er hat ein Muttermal auf der Stirn")